# Documentation sorted by return type

Tags: discussion, status-completed, documentation

Right now [the documentation is pretty terribly organized](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).  For example, consider the things under the "**Users**" heading:

- `/users` => returns [Users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)
- `/users/{ids}` => returns [Users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)
- `/users/{ids}/answers` => returns [Answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer)
- `/users/{ids}/badges` => returns [Badges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge)
- `/users/{ids}/comments` => returns [Comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment)
- `/users/{ids}/comments/{toid}` => returns [Comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment)
- `/users/{ids}/favorites` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/mentioned` => returns [Comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment)
- `/users/{id}/privileges` => returns [Privileges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/privilege)
- `/users/{ids}/questions` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/questions/no-answers` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/questions/unaccepted` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/questions/unanswered` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/reputation` => returns [Reputations](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation)
- `/users/{ids}/suggested-edits` => returns [Suggested Edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit)
- `/users/{ids}/tags` => returns [Tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag)
- `/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers` => returns [Answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer)
- `/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-questions` => returns [Questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- `/users/{ids}/timeline` => returns [User Timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline)
- `/users/{id}/top-answer-tags` => returns [Top Tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/top-tag)
- `/users/{id}/top-question-tags` => returns [Top Tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/top-tag)
- `/users/moderators` => returns [Users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)
- `/users/moderators/elected` => returns [Users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)
- `/users/{id}/inbox` => returns [Inbox Items](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item)
- `/users/{id}/inbox/unread` => returns [Inbox Items](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item)

Under this single heading, there are ***12*** different return types.  In fact, the *only* thing these methods seem to have in common is that the path starts with "`/users`", because not all of them even take user ids.

So: can we *please* get a more sane organization of the documentation page?  Something like this would be **AWESOME**:

### Things that produce Users:

- `/users`
- `/users/{user ids}`
- `/users/moderators`
- `/users/moderators/elected`
- `/tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}`
- `/tags/{tag}/top-askers/{period}`

### Things that produce Answers:

- `/users/{user ids}/answers`
- `/users/{user id}/tags/top-answers`
- `/answers`
- `/answers/{answer ids}`
- `/questions/{question ids}/answers`
- ...

### Things that produce Questions:

- `/users/{user ids}/favorites`
- `/users/{user ids}/questions/no-answers`
- `/users/{user ids}/questions/unaccepted`
- `/users/{user ids}/questions/unanswered`
- `/users/{user id}/tags/{tags}/top-questions`
- ...

... etc

Organizing things by what they return and not (seemingly) what the first part of their endpoint path is would make things *much* easier to find.

Comment: And to emphasize how much I think this should be done, I will gladly put up the maximum bounty if people need convincing.

Comment: +1 a list of [types](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/) would be nice as well (without having to go into the method page)

Comment: Hooray for `status-planned`!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... sort of.  I'm still planning on putting something fancy on `/docs/types` (there's nothing there now) but haven't quite worked out what yet.

Anyhoo, the main `/docs` page now has tabs

[image]

which change how methods are grouped.

"by category" returns methods as they always have been (by site / non-site, then by "what you're thinking about" [give me answers, give me answer comments, etc.]).  "by type" groups by "top level types" (things actually returned by methods) and then by the actual type returned (listing "member types" that aren't returned by any method directly separately).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've just discovered that at the bottom of each "type" page, there's a list with this information.  For example: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user#methods  This is insanely useful.  But it's in a hard-to-find location, especially since there isn't a comprehensive list of types anywhere.

Comment: It would be much better to have it on one page like you suggested.